# try to split "8" string in objective-c of iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, split

I am trying to split the string "8" and achieve only the String = 8 in Objective-C of iOS application.

I have a String with " character, so I am trying to do split (' " '); in objective C and I can't achieve only the character 8. For example, I read that to do an split in objective C I have to use

NSArray *array = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

but in @" " I can't insert the character " to separate it of character 8

Can you help me?

Comment: I didn't understood your question. Split a NSString with one character only? In an array?

Comment: Can you clarify your question please. Its hard to read what you want

Comment: I have a String with " character, so I am trying to do split (' " '); in objective C and I can't achieve only the character 8. For example, I read that to do an split in objective C I have to use 

NSArray *array = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

but in @" " I can't insert the character " to separate it of character 8

Comment: You can escape the `"` with a backslash. `@"\""` would be valid split term.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
    NSString *sWithQuotes = @"\"8\"";
    NSArray * components = [sWithQuotes componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
    NSLog(@"Eigth: %@", components[1]);
```